# Как достать Id запроса у юкассы

Tags: python, django

Короче суть вопроса.У меня есть админка и туда приходят новые заказы,но они туда приходят в любом случае,успешно ли либо не успешно оформлен заказ,в чем суть мне нужно проверять статус заказа после его оплаты и добавлять данные в админку,но чтобы проверить статус заказа нужно запомнить id самого заказа,во первых даже если я пытаюсь его запомнить таким образом `payment_id = request.POST.get('payment_id')`,то ничего не выходит `(payment_id =` request.POST.get('id') так тоже).Так `Payment.find_one(payment_id)` он выводит такую ошибку

ValueError at /orders/create/

Invalid payment_id value

```
payment_id = request.POST.get('payment_id')
payment = Payment.find_one(payment_id)
if payment_id.status == 'succeeded':
```

то есть по сути я хочу вот так сделать,но каждый раз выходит ошибка.Помогите пожалуйста,уже очень долго мучаюсь с этим,если что это Юкасса
Весь код выглядит так

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():



        # очистка корзины
        total_price = 0
        for item in cart:
            total_price += item['price'] * item['quantity']


        payment = Payment.create({

            "amount": {
                "value": total_price,  # передаем цену товара в виде строки
                "currency": "RUB"
            },
            'status':'waiting_for_capture',
            "confirmation": {
                "type": "redirect",
                "return_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home"
            },
            "capture": True,
            "description": f"Заказ товара "  # использование названия товара для описания заказа
        },uuid.uuid4())
        # payment = Payment.find_one(payment_id)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(payment.confirmation.confirmation_url)
        
        # return render(request, 'orders/order/created.html', {'order': order})
else:
    form = OrderCreateForm()
payment_id = request.GET.get('payment_id')
payment = Payment.find_one(payment_id)
if payment and payment.status == 'succeeded':
    # если платеж найден и его статус "succeeded"
    print('Статус заказа Юкассы:', payment_id)
else:
    # обработать другие статусы платежа
    print('Статус заказа Юкассы:', payment.status)

return render(request, 'orders/order/create.html', {'cart': cart, 'form': form})
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь получить значение `payment_id` из POST запроса, в котором его нет. Проверьте какие данные отправляются в Вашем POST запросе.

Comment: GET тоже не работает все тоже самое

Comment: Добавьте в свой вопрос ту часть кода, из которой отправляется обрабатываемый в данном контроллере POST запрос

Comment: ну вот я весь код написал как он выглядит

Comment: я не знаю,может есть другой вариант достать это id